# Test setters and getters with CHAI

Tags: unit-testing, chai

I'm studying for an exam, and one of the tasks will be unit testing with Chai and Mocha, but couldn't quite understand how to test if a class has getter and settor methods for properties. Can you help me out? Here's a sample class from homework:

```
 class PaymentPackage {
    constructor(name, value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.VAT = 20;      // Default value    
        this.active = true; // Default value
      }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(newValue) {
    if (typeof newValue !== 'string') {
      throw new Error('Name must be a non-empty string');
    }
    if (newValue.length === 0) {
      throw new Error('Name must be a non-empty string');
    }
    this._name = newValue;
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

  set value(newValue) {
    if (typeof newValue !== 'number') {
      throw new Error('Value must be a non-negative number');
    }
    if (newValue < 0) {
      throw new Error('Value must be a non-negative number');
    }
    this._value = newValue;
  }

  get VAT() {
    return this._VAT;
  }

  set VAT(newValue) {
    if (typeof newValue !== 'number') {
      throw new Error('VAT must be a non-negative number');
    }
    if (newValue < 0) {
      throw new Error('VAT must be a non-negative number');
    }
    this._VAT = newValue;
  }

  get active() {
    return this._active;
  }

  set active(newValue) {
    if (typeof newValue !== 'boolean') {
      throw new Error('Active status must be a boolean');
    }
    this._active = newValue;
}
```

}

Comment: I recommend reading [how do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward. You get the instance of your class and test the getter/setters one by one.

```js
describe("The class PaymentPackage", function () {

   function getInstance () {
      return new PaymentPackage("A", 1)
   }

   it("should have a getter property 'name'", function () {
      const paymentPackage = getInstance()
      expect(paymentPackage.name).to.be.a("string").and.equal("A")
   })

   it("should have a setter property 'name'", function () {
      const paymentPackage = getInstance()
      paymentPackage.name = "B"
      expect(paymentPackage.name).to.be.a("string").and.equal("B")
   })

})
```

Comment: Thank you, now I get it